# Compilation error, .NET is not seeing a function that exists

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I have a class library with the following method.

```
namespace TNAUtilities
{
    public class Database
    {
        public static DataView GetDataView(string query)
        {
            //actual implementation omitted, returns a DataView
        }
    }
}
```

I've used this method hundreds of times, the class library is a utility library I include in all my projects. However, now I'm working on a ASP.NET web site, and one of the web pages can't seem to see that method. The other pages in my site are able to see it.

```
using TNAUtilities; //top of class

//inside a method body
Database.GetDataView(query); // throws compilation error: 'Database' does not contain a definition for 'GetDataView'
```

This is the weirdest error I've seen. Intellisense is able to recognize it for code completion purposes, but Visual Studio 2010 Pro highlights the method call in blue. I actually call this method twice on the same page, both lines give the error. I tried doing a `Build -> Clean Solution` but it didn't help.

I've deployed the code to the server a couple of times, and the server reports the same issue. What could be the culprit here?

Comment: May be in this particular context there is another class, field or namespace named `Database`? Have you tried deleting all other code and 'using' statements, may be it could help localizing the problem?

Comment: Did you try to restart visual studio?

Comment: @golergka Ah, now I feel silly. I thought I would get a compilation error alerting me if there are two classes with the same name. But apparently not. In my web site project, I had created a page called `Database.aspx` which defaulted to a class name of `Database`. Which hid `TNAUtilities.Database`. Even though Intellisense code completion showed all the methods from the `TNAUtilities.Database` class. Funny that in all the other pages in my web site project, I didn't get compilation errors (and this Database.aspx page has existed for a while!) Make your comment into an answer for acceptance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

May be in this particular context there is another class, field or namespace named `Database`?